# protect_identifiers issue in codeigniter 3.1.0

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

In Previous version 2.2.6 i was using following code:

```
$this->db->_protect_identifiers=false;

$dataField='tm.*,IFNULL(CONCAT_WS(" " ,pm.firstName,pm.lastName),"") as assignedToName,IFNULL(cm.caseNo,"") as CaseNo,IFNULL(cm1.fileNo,"") as fileNo,IFNULL(sm.caseStage,"") as caseStage';

$qryTable='task_mst as tm 
            LEFT JOIN case_mst as cm on tm.caseNo=cm.ID
            LEFT JOIN case_mst as cm1 on tm.fileNo=cm1.ID
            LEFT JOIN party_mst as pm on tm.assignedTo=pm.ID
            LEFT JOIN session_mst as sm on tm.sessionId=sm.ID';
$task= $this->db->select($dataField,false)->from($qryTable)->where($where,NULL,FALSE)->order_by("ID","desc")->limit(10)->get()->result_array();
```

Now i am using Version 3.1.0 but "_protect_identifiers" will give error message

```
Fatal error: Cannot access protected property CI_DB_mysqli_driver::$_protect_identifiers
```

Can anyone tell me how to use "protect_identifiers()" in codeigniter 3.1.0?

Comment: Perhaps it now requires an accessor method such as `set_protect_identifiers(false);` or some variation of that. Let me know if so and I will post as answer.

Answer (score 2):

Simply remove the _ from the $this->db->_protect_identifiers. (Underscore Symbol)

```
$this->db->protect_identifiers=false;
```

This is the change CI made in new version.

Answer (score 1):

here is a sample

```
return 'SELECT '.$this->escape_identifiers('name')
            .' FROM '.$this->escape_identifiers('sysobjects')
            .' WHERE '.$this->escape_identifiers('type')." = 'U'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set like this..

```
$this->db->protect_idenifiers(FALSE)->select(...)->where(...)
```

For more refer [this](http://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-62478.html).

Comment: I used "$task= $this->db->protect_identifiers(FALSE)->select($dataField,FALSE)->from($qryTable)->where($where,NULL,FALSE)->order_by("ID","desc")->limit(10)->get()->result_array();" but it give me error "Call to a member function select() on a non-object"

Comment: This error may be occurs when database library is not load.. The first way is to include the "database" in your application/config/autoload.php `$autoload['libraries'] = array('database')`; or load in your class constructor by `$this->load->database()`;