# Cannot access protected property CI_DB_mysqli_driver::$_protect_identifiers

Tags: codeigniter

I am getting 
Cannot access protected property CI_DB_mysqli_driver::$_protect_identifiers
Code as follows

```
function xyz($use_protech_identifier = false)
{
 $this->db->_protect_identifiers=$use_protech_identifier;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this. May be this will work because of latest CI Version.
**Remove the _ from protect_identifiers.**

```
$this->db->protect_identifiers=$use_protech_identifier;
```

Also refer the same answer I gave in https://stackoverflow.com/a/50738006/3449206

Answer (score 0):

or my fav solution : go to "\system\database\DB_driver.php" change "protected $_protect_identifiers     = TRUE;" to "public $_protect_identifiers       = TRUE;" and u have essential claim bob to be ur uncle - so bobs ur uncle!